# Prove a curvature identity

Tags: curvature

Show that **N** = (d**T**/dt)/(abs (d**T**/dt))
using d**T**/ds = k **N**

Answer (score 0):

First,
$$\frac{ d\mathbf T }{ dt } = \frac{ d\mathbf T }{ ds } \, \frac{ ds }{ dt } = k' \mathbf N,$$
where $k' = k \, (ds/dt)$.
But since $\|\mathbf N\|$ = 1, we have
$$\left\| \frac{ d \mathbf T }{ dt } \right\| = k'.$$
So
$$\mathbf N = \frac{ d \mathbf T / dt } { k'} = \frac{ d \mathbf T / dt } { \left\|d \mathbf T / dt \right\| }.$$